# How would I go about using a multidimensional array variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Hi there before I start I did try looking through the search about writing variables so if this has been asked and answered then I do apologise but this is baffling me ....

So here goes ..

example of what I am talking about

```
var i = e[ab]  
var n = e[cd][ef]  
var t = e[cd][gh]
```

I know that when I want var i I can put e.ab but how would I go about writing var n and var t

Comment: that's a multidimensional array, there's no such thing as a "double variable"

Comment: It (e) is an array of arrays, what is the problem?

Comment: Could also be a nested object; either way, you have some reading to do!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. "when I want var i", you already have var i, just use it?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I did not know what to call it javascript variables is not my strong point and I have been trying to read on it all day hence why I decided to ask for help here

Comment: Your edit doesn't clear anything up. What do you mean you're pulling `[ab]` then `[cd]` etc. from a JSON file? JSON isn't formatted like that. It seems like you're having trouble accessing data from an object. Perhaps if you showed us an example object it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming your object looks like this (based on your description, it sounds like you want to access an object which is the property of another object), and you want to access them through the indexer properties (which would be a property of a property).

```
 var e = {
      ab : "variableOne",
      cd : {ef:"ef object"},
      gh : {ij:"ij object"},
   }

   var i = e["ab"] 
   //if these are properties, then you need to add quotes around them
   //to access a property through the indexer, you need a string.
   var n = e["cd"]["ef"]  
   var t = e["gh"]["ij"]

   console.log(i);
   console.log(n);
   console.log(t);

   console.log("this does the same thing:")
   console.log(e.ab);
   console.log(e.cd.ef);
   console.log(e.gh.if);
```

In your example the object would look like

```
//e is the parameter, but I show it as a variable to show 
// it's relation to the object in this example.

e = {
    now_playing: {artist:"Bob Seger"; track:"Turn the Page"}}
}
```

this is different than an array of arrays:

```
 var arr = [
      ['foo','charlie'],
      ['yip', 'steve'],
      ['what', 'bob', 'jane'],
   ];


   console.log(arr[0][0]); //foo 
   console.log(arr[0][1]); //charlie
   console.log(arr[1][0]); //yip
   console.log(arr[1][1]); //steve
   console.log(arr[2][2]); //jane
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joo9wfxt/2/

EDIT: 
   Based on the JSON provided, it looks like parameter `e` in the function is assigned the value of the item in the array.  With your code:

this line will display: "Rock you like a hurricane - Nontas Tzivenis"

```
$(".song_title .current_show span").html(e.title);
```

and this line will display: "Rascal Flatts - Life is a Highway".

```
$(".song_title .current_song span").html(e.np);
```

If it's not displaying you might want to double check your JQuery selectors.  This `".song_title .current_song span"` [is selecting it by the classes on the element](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/).

Comment: Hi there I have updated my question with the proper code that I am trying to use original code worked on old site I am simply trying to update it to work on new one any hints or pointers in the correct direction would be helpful not looking for anyone to do the work for me just been banging my head against the wall with this for hours which is why I asked on here in first place thank you for your explanations so far

Comment: Can you post what the JSON looks like that you are getting from the getJson function?

Comment: json structure example added for you to see

Comment: Ok ill take a look when I get back from dinner

Comment: Thanks for looking at it and trying to help out I already knew what the old functions did what I was trying to achieve is have the artist and track separate which I have now managed to do this in php thank you very much for your assistance and talking to me like a human and not just slating me like some of the others basically did :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in need of a bit of a refresher on basic JavaScript syntax.  Here's how you can assign an "empty object" to a variable, then start to assign values to it's properties:

```
e = {}
e.ab = {}
e.cd = {}
e.cd.ef = "data"
```

or you can use the associative array syntax for property access:

```
e = {}
e["ab"] = {}
e["cd"] = {}
e["cd"]["ef"] = "data"
```

You see the latter is using the object `e` like a two-deep associative array.  Is that what you are looking to do?

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is not strongly typed. So an Array "a" could contain objects of different types inside.

```
var a = [ "a value", [1, 2, 3], function(){ return 5 + 2;}];

var result = a[0]; //get the first item in my array: "a value"
var resultOfIndexedProperty = a[1][0]; //Get the first item of the second item: 1
var resultOfFunc = a[2](); //store the result of the function that is the third item of my array: 7
```

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: How would that help? OP was not confused about Javascripts type system.

Comment: It appeared to me that he was questioning if `e[x][y]` was going to give him the object at (x,y) in his multidimensional array. Perhaps I've misinterpreted the question.